# Does set_visible in perl WWW:mechanize alter the page content

Tags: perl, mechanize, www-mechanize

I am calling set_visible and the return value is non-zero. But when I print the content, it is the same as the default. Is this the intended value.

Also, if I have javascript that will change another field, when will that execute (or does it)?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific with your `set_visible` question - sample code would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in [the FAQ](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFAQ#JavaScript), WWW::Mechanize does not run Javascript.